# raspberry pi でスイッチを押したら割り込みでcallback関数を使ってwhileループを抜けたい

Tags: python

今ロボット制作でraspberry pi 4 でスイッチを押したら割り込みでcallback関数を呼び出してその時点でメインループを抜ける処理を行いたいです。
できますでしょうか。
できないのであれば理由を教えていただけますでしょうか

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def callback():
    //ここにcallback関数の処理

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
//BCMの11番ピンを入力に設定
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN) 
GPIO.add_event_detect(11, GPIO.FALLING, callback= callback, bouncetime=300)

while True:
    //メインループ
```